# Led indicator for current flow direction

Tags: led, current-measurement, lithium-ion, indicator

I want to make a lithium ion charge and discharge indicator using red and green led. While battery is charging red led should glow and during discharge via load it should glow green.

Comment: You could use a dual-supply comparator on a small current sensing resistor and a bipolar LED; how much current are we talking about?

Comment: @vir can you describe this with circuit diagram

Comment: @vir 1 amp for charging and upto 2 amp for discharging

Comment: Just keep in mind that to someone who's red/green colorblind, a red/green LED is either on or off.  So you'll frustrate 6% of the male population and about 0.1% of the women.  **Separate** LEDs will be definitive for everyone who can see.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_blindness#Design_implications

Comment: @TimWescott is right.  But if you're set on R/G you can, with added complexity, overload the indicator (e.g. flashing red/steady green). OR using a single LED, one of my recent (one-off) designs uses a red LED with dim flashing=ready, steady bright=firing, steady dim=wait, for example

Comment: We're totally OT on this whole indicator thing -- but I'm sure there's people who have "flash dislexia", so encoding too much into one light is also trouble.  There's a whole science behind this, and I only scratch the surface; most people who are serious about covering as many bases as possible use multiple different ways (different shapes, colors, blink rates, etc.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My preference is to sense high-side. The main consideration when doing that is to choose an op-amp that allows for the inputs to go at least to or above the Vcc supply ('above the rails'). Fortunately there are some choices available, like the LT1490.

The op-amp should also have low input offset (less than 1mV if possible), since the sensing differential voltages involved are in the tens of mV. If your current is lower, you can relax this spec by using a higher value sense resistor.

This design uses an 'above the rail' capable op-amp (assume the op-amp power supply is from the load side) as a comparator:

[Simulate it here](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWEDoDYCcAmMYDMncAWVMBXXADhEN3CVUmQFMBaHAKACcRNIqxUIXJELhBjGJEzsBmaqlGYKVYqNwI5cgCZMAZgEMArgBsALi2NMt4KLclh2AdyGp%20SoRvDvIXHsq9U6nJg3jzS3Er8DB7B0YyY0s6UogKMQWISMqhyhFSR1IGe2npGZhZWthASsA7cqQFhKaEJvvX1CSlxYU7ghE1uA1A9bdEhUZnOmADswe7TOVQ%20k4SMYzwrBUOTmP3rq949O6vRHRlbIAq9orlX5-MNR2dLew8zTz3CnTxvN8%20PN7wokNuKo-CpLo9GCs4MNRnD4jshgBLGIgFj4VEsdDiKCwSAMeCEomQBDsADmmIx6TYOJ8AA8CoFcBAENihERqOsQAARJEAZwAxgALfScMlMdgMhCCFgICB4OQsG6KUQAIX0plMTE4AE9JdQEmiEKJpVRZRAVSAADIAe30WgA9ABhEVi7U9G5gPqbU7PUFe64QxF%20gGI0G%20j6eerpCNJCiKREx4OHPhiHiprHiD4iNFsz5pv15Dah0Q%20ABuZ3RsUYLAoElsGy9dlxpIp9SrlYEdlhNbrlbZfwzbPbA%20zokzmNHDNlUyEmHQPAg5ByXJdovFvgB-gBGyh8A9QcDKsydW9pz7vvAxJ7jVusZAF7DeWTIJLQnjt9W18m-jW9zWfy-icbz1D4%20gNAGFwpN6-BIF%20RK9HixLwKQhALl6SFerwAgUDM6AYmARLsOByS3P6MF0JUxKIShvCQGA6CMQgJKzng0CMdiWBwKgUxTMxUy0IRhIHqIfbkaWHyuA%20aRSQBHpUGJ-Des8kF9pBckCtJWk4HIfarKwhHgEhRI8XAeALpI9HsJp0JaTQun1mABmrIQmF0QgGjYpQuJmTeazqQczg6dpMETFpilaX6lxiRiekfB%20ay4LJgUuApe6MHFFI3Ok2VSZkWWXDlhV5UMNq2Jce7oIseIhLwUyQMymBwdAiw8LYuDsN5ho1jAVTQBATqGJwnBMAAdqY7BAA):

[image]

This has hysteresis. It's set up for about +/-14mA here.

If a non- 'above the rail' op-amp is used, then apply a voltage divider to the op-amp inputs. This rules out using hysteresis however and consumes more power.

The same approach can be used for low-side sense too, but beware: the same issue comes up with the inputs. Choose an op-amp that can work with the inputs *below* Vss, as the sense to the battery is either polarity. Again, if that kind of an op-amp isn't an option, a voltage divider can be used, but forget using hysteresis.

Finally, some further reading. ADI has a collection some good (but probably more expensive) current-sensing ideas here: https://www.analog.com/en/app-notes/an-105fa.html

Answer (score 7):

Maybe something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foIXbq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This circuit uses a [MCP6V7](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MCP6V66-Family-Data-Sheet-DS20006266A.pdf) dual op-amp as a comparator. It will detect a current of less than 10mA in either direction (threshold about +/-180uV). Voltage drop is 20mV at 1A. Iq is typically less than 200uA (with neither LED on).

Comment: I think a little clean-up is required on the schematic. You have "to battery" as well as BAT1 and haven't shown where to connect the load. It might be worth pointing out that the circuit GND will be up to 20 mA *above* battery negative during discharge and *below* when charging due to the voltage drop across R1. +1.

Comment: @Transistor One side of the battery is (almost) grounded. BAT1 is the component designator. Use like a battery with the negative grounded. Edit added.